# How do I limit input time spacing in SQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to make an input form that contains "clock in" and "clock out" and "space" but what I worry about is when I enter the time between the hours.

I want the space code to only be filled by a certain period of time (hours of entry and hours out) and I want that the distance between these times to not be filled.

As an example:
the input
space code: FL2
Check-in time: 10:00
Out time: 12.00

** at the time of the next input
space code: FL2 (same code as above)
Check-in time: 11:00 (it should not be able to be filled in, because it is within the time interval that was entered)
Out time: 2:00

How can I do this so that the input process above (**) cannot fill the time between the intervals that already exist?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.